# how to infinite loop function that outputs the quadrant of a coordinate on a graph

Tags: python

i was writing this program to figure out the quadrant of a coordinate on a graph but couldn't figure out how to make It loop. i tried while True and it errors. any help/ tips are appreciated

```
x =int(input("enter x coordinate: "))
y = int(input("\nenter y coordinate: "))

def quadrant(x, y): 
if (x > 0 and y > 0): 
    print (quad, "lies in First quadrant") 

elif (x < 0 and y > 0): 
    print (quad, "lies in Second quadrant") 
      
elif (x < 0 and y < 0): 
    print (quad, "lies in Third quadrant") 
  
elif (x > 0 and y < 0): 
    print (quad, "lies in Fourth quadrant") 
      
elif (x == 0 and y > 0): 
    print (quad, "lies at positive y axis") 
  
elif (x == 0 and y < 0): 
    print (quad, "lies at negative y axis") 
  
elif (y == 0 and x < 0): 
    print (quad, "lies at negative x axis") 
  
elif (y == 0 and x > 0): 
    print (quad, "lies at positive x axis") 
  
else: 
    print (quad, "lies at origin") 
   
quad= (x,y)
quadrant(x, y)
```

Comment: *How exactly* did you try to use `while True:`?

Comment: i added while true before the first line and indented the rest of the code to work with while true

Comment: Show the code that produces the error in the question.

Comment: i got it to stop saying errors but now it only loops the first two lines 
    x =int(input("enter x coordinate: "))
    y = int(input("\nenter y coordinate: "))

Answer (score 0):

```
def quadrant(x, y):
    if (x > 0 and y > 0):
        print (quad, "lies in First quadrant")

    elif (x < 0 and y > 0):
        print (quad, "lies in Second quadrant")

    elif (x < 0 and y < 0):
        print (quad, "lies in Third quadrant")

    elif (x > 0 and y < 0):
        print (quad, "lies in Fourth quadrant")

    elif (x == 0 and y > 0):
        print (quad, "lies at positive y axis")

    elif (x == 0 and y < 0):
        print (quad, "lies at negative y axis")

    elif (y == 0 and x < 0):
        print (quad, "lies at negative x axis")

    elif (y == 0 and x > 0):
        print (quad, "lies at positive x axis")

    else:
        print (quad, "lies at origin")


while True:
    x = int(input("enter x coordinate: "))
    y = int(input("\nenter y coordinate: "))
    quad= (x,y)
    quadrant(x, y)
```

i think this is work

Answer (score 0):

```
while(True):
    x =int(input("enter x coordinate: "))
    y = int(input("\nenter y coordinate: "))
    quad= (x,y)
    quadrant(x, y)
```

Also remove your input in first two lines as that's included here.
This might be what you asked for as your question is not clear.